# how to substitute all occurrences of a substring with parameters in Java?

Tags: java, string, substitution

I have the following string:

```
"useless text $TABLE[1]$ other useless text $TABLE[2]$ useless text..."
```

I want to substitute the occurrences of the substring "*$TABLE[x]$*" with something like "*< table id='x'>*". So I need to get back the id from the string and to insert in the substituting string, and this for all the occurrences.

Something like this:

```
text = text.replace("$TABLE_[x]$", "<table id='x'>");
```

Comment: If you want to replace all of them, why not use [`replaceAll()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use regex with groups:

```
text.replaceAll("(\\$TABLE\\[)(\\d+)(\\]\\$)", "<table id=$2>");
```

`$2` references the second group (one or more digits), which is the id of the table